# AWS RDS MySQL connection limits

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a MySQL database server, db.t3.micro, parameter group is 'default.mysql8.0', max_connections is '{DBInstanceClassMemory/12582880}'

I figured out that it cannot handle more than ~63 connections

According to AWS RDS documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Limits.html#RDS_Limits.MaxConnections

Connection limit for Mysql is calculated using '{DBInstanceClassMemory/12582880}' formula, where  DBInstanceClassMemory tier instance memory in bytes.

So for db.t3.micro 1Gb it is 1073741824/12582880 = 85

‘SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "max_connections";’ returns 63

| Tier | Memory, GiB | Memory, Bytes | Calculated connection limit | Real connection limit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| db.t3.micro | 1 | 1073741824 | 85 | 63 |
| db.t3.small | 2 | 2147483648 | 170 | 146 |
| db.t3.2xlarge | 32 | 32x1073741824 | 2720 | 2634 |

Why real connections limit is less than the formula result?

Comment: Have you tried updating the value? Might be that it's running out of memory on that small server and can't handle and more and AWS has updated the value.

Comment: I've added a db.t3.2xlarge case, servers have no load, and current memory usage doesn't make any sense, DBInstanceClassMemory - is total amount of the memory

Comment: I don't think this isn't the type of thing many people would have done. It might be worth getting AWS support for a month, if no-one here can help. I'd have a good search for documentation and blog articles first though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So DBInstanceClassMemory is actually TotalMemory- (Memory consumed by OS + other processes)

Amazon documentation clearly says

> db.m5.xlarge instance class. DBInstanceClassMemory is 16 GiB, or
> 17,179,869,184 bytes

but that is not true, and real DBInstanceClassMemory will be less than 16GiB

Comment: Are you suggesting that connection limits are based on memory available after OS and other processes are running? That would seem reasonable, as connections do take memory, but if that's the case the documentation should probably be clarified. If you provide feedback on the AWS documentation using their links I find AWS staff often respond and update pages based on reasonable suggestions.

Comment: yep, I did that